# How to save Windows 7 taskbar toolbars into the toolbar list permently?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, toolbar

Taskbar toolbars are really useful for projects I have open but when I'm done and I untick that toolbar from the list to display it goes forever and I have to remake it by doing the following each time...

Right click task bar > Toolbars > New toolbar...

Is there a way to get it to save the toolbars I make permanently?

Answer (score 2):

For information: The taskbar's setup is stored in the following registry key :
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Desktop`.

However, the contents are in binary, so not that easy to change.

The solution could be to use regedit to export the above registry key in its two states : with or without the toolbar. The only hitch is that Explorer has probably to be restarted for the change to take effect, which can be done with a batch file.

Here is a suggestion for such a .bat file :

```
regedit.exe /s "path of .reg file"
taskkill explorer.exe
explorer.exe
```

If anything is missing, you could use [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to trace the "Toolbars -> New toolbar" operation, to see what else is changed in the registry when the toolbar is added.